# Computing the expected value of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to compute the following expectation
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\int_0^{t \land \tau_n} \varepsilon ds
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon$ is a positive constant and $\tau_n$ is a stopping time. I know, by hypotesis that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_n = \infty)=\delta > 0$. I would like to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\int_0^{t \land \tau_n} \ge \varepsilon \delta t
\end{equation*}
It is correct to write:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{t \land \tau_n}\varepsilon ds\right] =\int_0^{t \land \tau_n}\varepsilon ds \mathbb{P}(\tau_n = \infty)+\int_0^{t \land \tau_n}\varepsilon ds \mathbb{P}(\tau_n < \infty)
\end{equation}

Comment: No, your last equation is not correct -- the LHS is an expectation (just a number), whereas the RHS is a random variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\varepsilon$ is a constant, the integral is just $\varepsilon\ (t\land\tau_n)$. Now use the fact that $$t\land\tau_n = t\ [t\le\tau_n] + \tau_n\ [t>\tau_n]\ge t\ [t\le\tau_n]\ge t\ [\tau_n = \infty]$$ where $[\ ]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), so $$\mathbb{E}( t\land\tau_n) \ge t\ P(\tau_n=\infty)$$
and the required inequality follows.

---

Alternatively, you could use conditional expectations as follows for any $t<\infty$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\int_0^{t \land \tau_n}\varepsilon ds
&=\varepsilon\ \mathbb{E} (t \land \tau_n) \\
&= \varepsilon\ \bigg( \mathbb{E}(t \land \tau_n|\tau_n=\infty )P(\tau_n=\infty) + \mathbb{E}(t \land \tau_n|\tau_n<\infty )P(\tau_n<\infty)\bigg)\\
&= \varepsilon\bigg( t\  P(\tau_n=\infty) + \mathbb{E}(t \land \tau_n|\tau_n<\infty )P(\tau_n<\infty)\bigg)\\
&\ge \varepsilon\bigg(t\ P(\tau_n=\infty) \bigg)
\end{align}$$